# How to use variable value for shell command in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have one shell command that uses some argument that is being invoked from Python script :

```
cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 --num-threads=2 run > cpu_sysbench.txt'
```

Now I wanted to define -cpu-max-prime value as a varible and use it:

```
prime_numbers = "20000"
cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=$prime_numbers --num-threads=2 run'
```

But when I run it I see few syntax errors:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
prime_numbers = "20000"
cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime={} --num-threads=2 run'.format(prime_numbers)
# --> sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 --num-threads=2 run
```

Comment: Hello @Rakesh, actually the complete command is , "cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 --num-threads=2 run > cpu_sysbench.txt'"

Comment: Did you use `cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime={} --num-threads=2 run > cpu_sysbench.txt'.format(prime_numbers)` ?

Comment: Cool, this one worked for me, even for print it can be used  ?

Comment: would like to use num-threads variable together with  prime_numbers, what should be the exact syntax for same ?

Comment: `cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime={} --num-threads={} run > cpu_sysbench.txt'.format(prime_numbers, num_threads)` OR `cmd = 'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime={prime_numbers} --num-threads={num_threads} run > cpu_sysbench.txt'.format(prime_numbers=prime_numbers, num_threads=num_threads)`

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
cmd = f'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime={prime_numbers} --num-threads=2 run'
```

This is called an f-string, it's an easy way to format strings in Python >= 3.6. Of course you could also just use string concatenation or other methods, this is not at all specific to running shell commands.

Comment: this is what I see:cmd = f'sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 --num-threads=2 run > cpu_sysbench.txt'
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The difference is that here we're using [fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Comment: @FilipMłynarski The OP appears to be using something older than 3.5, so f-strings aren't available.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string formatting at all. Build a *list* consisting of the command name and its arguments as separate elements for use with `subprocess.Popen` (or one of its wrapper functions).

```
prime_numbers = "20000"
cmd = [
    'sysbench',
    '--test=cpu',
    '--cpu-max-prime',
    prime_numbers,
    '--num-threads=2',
    'run'
]

with open("cpu_sysbench.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=f)
    # or subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=f) in older Python 3.x
```

Update: to incorporate a `grep` command, use two subprocesses with their standard input and standard output joined.

```
with open("cpu_sysbench.txt", "w") as f:

    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # grep + cut can almost always be replaced by a single awk
    subprocess.call(['awk', '-F', ':', '/total time:/ { print $2 }'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=f)
```

Comment: tried running abobe snippets but seeing this, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `subprocess.run` was introduced in 3.5.

Comment: actually if I run it using python3 script_name it works but if just run it ./script_name it fails

Comment: Also, have to apply grep command on the cpu_sysbench.txt file, cmd = [ 'grep', 'total time:', "cpu_sysbench.txt" | cut -d ':' -f2 " ] but it seems to failing for syntax

Comment: Because `|` isn't an argument. If you want a good answer, you need to be clear about what you are actually asking.